# Born on the same day, but one is two years older

Tags: knowledge, time

Two people were born on the same day, same year, and share the same birthday.

One is 2 years old, the other is only a few days old.

**What's going on here?**

Answer (score 48, accepted):

They were born on

> the New Year's Eve (not necessarily of the western variety), and one of the families is using [the East Asian way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Asian_age_reckoning) to measure age.

Comment: @Saeïdryl because one of them were 1 year old already at the moment he/she was born, so next year this person goes on 2. This answer can be more accurate if this _New Year's Eve_ comes from the **lunar calender**.

Comment: @ShaneHsu I confused myself by reading New Year's Eve instead of New Year's Day on Wikipedia...
I get it, Bass' "New Year's Eve" refers to Asian Eve and not December the 31st. But that's not clear!

Comment: @Saeïdryl that's a fair point. Edited.

Comment: But aren't we assuming that the children belong to different families? The answer below using science seems more appropriate. =P

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Did the question ever specify "twins"? The way I'm reading the revisions, it _always_ said "two people", which can be pretty easily interpreted to mean "two people [from different families]".

Comment: Well mostly only the Koreans seem to still do it in the current era. It's obsolete in China and Japan.

Answer (score 74):

We'll just apply a bit of science assuming they were born in same year as well:

> The younger kid was put in a spaceship that rotated around the galaxy at ultra-high speed and came back to earth.

Comment: this can be the only correct answer

Comment: youngest astronaut alive

Comment: Since days are no doubt calculated in Earth's reference frame, and we can assume that even a spherical, frictionless baby would malfunction if subjected to constant acceleration exceeding 20g, it would take almost three weeks to accelerate an initially stationary baby to the required speed. Therefore this answer is slightly inaccurate, and the other baby must have been *born* on the already relativistic spaceship.

Comment: "...a spherical frictionless baby..." only on puzzling.SE would one expect such a phrase

Comment: @Bass for a civilization to have a spaceship that can go around a galaxy at ultra-high speed, they can have the tech to protect the baby... Also, if we just want to assume as much as we like, the travelling could have been done after the children grew up. You're not stating in the OP that they had a 2 year gap all their lives...

Comment: I bookmarked this question just to look back at this answer :D

Comment: @DarrenH Maybe on WorldBuilding.SE...

Comment: If the spaceship went all the way around the galaxy then the one who stayed on Earth would be hundreds of thousands of years older, not just two! It's better to say they went about a quarter of the way to the nearest star. (That's 4.2 light years away, so if you go a quarter of the way there and back again, that's about a 2 light year journey.)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Except the puzzle says "is", present tense. The travel would have to happen pretty soon after birth.

Comment: @aschepler you're right. Didn't see that. ;)

Comment: I joined this site solely so I could upvote the phrase "a spherical, frictionless baby"

Comment: A better solution that uses GR might be that there is a steep gravity gradient nearby and one baby is in a much stronger gravitational field than the other. That solves the problem of acceleration time. Infalling blue-shifted radiation is a possible concern, as are tidal forces if the source of the gradient is very small, so it would have to be big. A large neutron star might be the best thing. A neutron star also would not emit dangerous Hawking radiation (IIUC) which gives it an advantage over a black hole.

Comment: @DanielBeck Welcome to puzzling.SE, where we compete with WorldBuilding.SE to create spherical, frictionless babies.

Answer (score 46):

Apply some other bit of science, assuming they were born at the same time,

> .. but on Mercury.
>  According to [Mercury's Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(planet)), Mercury rotates extremely slowly, so
>  `An observer on Mercury would therefore see only one day every two years.`
>
>  The two people are the same age, they are both two years old, which on Mercury is equal to very few (*one*, to be precise) days.

Answer (score 36):

Is it lateral-thinking?

> They are born on the same day but not on the same year.

Comment: Different years means that it is not the same day, otherwise the puzzle should have read: "same day of the year" and not just "same day".

Comment: @BjarkeFreund-Hansen It is subjective, i.e. if I say "same hour" I never implied it was on the same day. So instead of posting about time relativity and twin paradox I decided to play on the lack of informations and lateral thinking.

Comment: @BjarkeFreund-Hansen: It's open to interpretation, which is often where the trick of a puzzle is located. Arguably, "the same day" could mean "Friday", "the 7th", "Jan 7th", or "Jan 7th 2017". You just can't be sure.

Answer (score 14):

location location location

> one lives at the north/south pole, where each day is 6 months long

Answer (score 6):

Sudden loss:

> One child died a few days after being born. The family refuses to acknowledge the age of the lost child as if it was alive and so while one is celebrating it's 2nd year of life the other will forever remain only a few days old.

Answer (score 4):

This could be an historical question

> The change from the Julian calendar to the Gregorian calendar didn't happen at the same time in every country.
>
>  If one person was born on February 29th in a country that was still under the Julian calendar, and the other was born on the same day in a country that was now on the Gregorian calendar, then one would have a birthday every year, while the other had one every four years, despite being born on the same day.

Answer (score 2):

It's a

> Twin Paradox!!
> Applying Einstein's Special theory of Relativity!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! You may find the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) interesting, where you'll earn an easy badge. I edited your answer with >! to hide your answer from others until they want to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Could it have anything to do with

> being born on February 29th? Where I come from people would say that if you were born on 29th February you can only celebrate your birthday that day which means 1 year only adds up every 4 years?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you edit your answer to include spoiler tags, so as not to spoil your solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves? Thanks!

Comment: Around 732 days later, this might explain saying one baby is "not yet one year old", but not really that the baby is "only a few days old"...

Answer (score 2):

It's all about space and time!

> They were born at same time but not in the same planet. Suppose that both were born at their respective planets at the same universal time (which on Earth would be, for example, March, 22th 1988).
>
>  But at the moment of answering this question both planets had completed different translations around their star. So if person A is at Earch he/she is now 30 years old, and if person B is at a planet which translation time is a little slower (so the planet have completed only 28 laps around it's star, rather than 30) he/she will have only the age of 28.

Comment: (Even for [tag:lateral-thinking] puzzles—which this is NOT—the solver is not given free license to invent their own rules or scenarios. Especially for puzzles not tagged "lateral thinking", the right answer to a puzzle will be the one that uses what the puzzle gave you or hinted at, without inventing facts, rules, or interpretations out of thin air to make a "solution" work. Puzzle posters can't close every loophole… and shouldn't have to.)

Answer (score -1):

One was born

> In the year 1 BC

And the other

> Year 1 AD